# Logic of indefinitely nested rows in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, nested, rows

I've been like a month trying to figure out this maybe its something very simple:

I have something similar to this Recipes table

> **Product     Ingredient  Qty**
>
> Lemonade    Lemon     2
>   Lemonade    Water     1
>   Lemonade    Sugar     6
>   Breakfast    Lemonade    1
>   Breakfast    Sandwich    1
>   Sandwich    Bread      2
>   Sandwich    Lettuce      1
>   Sandwich    Ham       3

And another table, Product,  with the properties of each one

> **Concept     Type**
>
> Lemonade    Product
>   Breakfast    Action
>   Sandwich    Product
>   Lemon     Supplie
>   Water     Supplie
>   Sugar     Supplie
>   Bread     Supplie
>   Lettuce     Supplie
>   Ham      Supplie

`this could be indefinitely nested` Examp. adding Day, and nest breakfast, dinner, lunch etc. each one with its nested products and each products with its nested supplies

- It is possible that in one query get the supplies used in a breakfast?
- or I have to change the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we often call a “BOM” in database land. (Bill of materials). So you might have an “electric motor assembly” and then that goes to a fan assembly and then hat goes into an air condition unit.
The ability to “add together” an un-limited amounts of assemblies is thus an often solved and requested problem in database land.

An Access example of such a design can be found here:

The http://access.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0027.htm

The above is in Access 97, so you have to “import” the example into recent versions of Access before use. You can also do a BinGoogle for “BOM”  database examples.

Comment: Tank you SO much, I couldn't open te file from the link with Access 2013
but you give me the name of the concept that's all I need